# CSS background-image showing in Chrome but not IE or Firefox

Tags: css

Below is the CSS for my main content section of my site.  The background image shows in Chrome, but not in IE11 or Firefox.  Any idea why?

```
#maincontent
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto !important;
    background-image: url(images/money-background.png);
    background-position: top; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: here you go: http://www.stock-up.biz/privacy_notloggedin.php

Comment: I can see it in FF, try clearing your cache

Comment: looks the same to me in FF and Chrome: http://grabilla.com/04518-0970f42c-cf30-49e7-ba87-be2af12cf3c3.html# only IE seems to not show it

Comment: hmm.. I'm running FF 9.0.1 and I don't see it even after clearing entire cache...

Comment: @Lenny See my answer below ;-)

Comment: For safari/firefox/ie, you should background and all transitions with the -webkit followed by whatever tag u wanna use. Not all browsers support features of html/css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `<main id="maincontent">` to `<div id="maincontent">`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  I thought the <main> tag was supported on all browsers with html5 but I guess not.. appreciate your help!